# Adding theme parameters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I have below ggplot

```
library(ggplot)
  library(ggcorrplot)
  data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)
head(corr[, 1:6])
ggcorrplot(corr, hc.order = TRUE, type = "upper", outline.col = "white") +
theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"), legend.position = "left") +
guides(color=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

I above case, I was trying to change the `legend` name to  `New Legend Title`, but unfortunately that did not happen.
I also want to add specific background colour to the entire plot and also change the colour scale for correlation from 'red' to 'blue'

Is there any way to achieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the legend is a guide for the `fill` aesthetic. Hence, use `fill` instead of `color`. Additionally the guide is a colorbar so you have to use `guide_colorbar`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

ggcorrplot(corr, hc.order = TRUE, type = "upper", outline.col = "white") +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm"), legend.position = "left") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "New Legend Title"))
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks. Is it possible to change the background colour and add a border around the actual plot (only containing the area for correlation colours)?

Comment: Try with `+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95"), panel.border = element_rect(linewidth = 2, fill = NA))`. Perhaps that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Is there any way to fix the order of plot same as the data? For example, in plot, `wt` comes after `carb`, however in data there is no such order. I want to keep order consistent

Comment: Set `hc.order=FALSE` which is the default so that the columns are ordered as in the data.